# Detecting sprites in C#-XNA

Tags: c#, xna, sprite

I'm developing a game of uno in C# & XNA.
At a certain stage of the game, I need to detect which card is at certain specific position.
So how can we detect which sprite is at a certain position by passing the screen co-ordinates??

Comment: I do not understand this question, doesn't the sprite have a position property that is used to draw it?

Comment: At certain stage i need to clear some of the cards from the screen which are placed at the certain position on the screen. So i need to locate the cards(sprites) at the specific co-ordinates

Comment: Don't do this based on screen position. That makes no sense unless it is literally their place on the screen which determines whether they should be cleared (I doubt this is true, it is probably some other criteria that causes both).

Comment: Don't just draw the cards on the screen and forget what you put there. Separate the game world and its representation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store the sprite positions in some variable and compare the screen coordinates to that variable. Since the sprite covers a certain area, you might want to store not only its origin but also its height and width; a Rectangle would do the job nicely.

Example:

```
class Game1
{
    List<Rectangle> cardSpriteAreas; // this is where you store the card's areas

    public void Update()
    {
         Point position = GetInterestingPosition(); // this is the point you want to check
         foreach(var spriteArea in cardSpriteAreas)
         {
              if (spriteArea.Contains(position))
              {
                   // position is contained within the card's area!
              }
         }
    }
}
```